# Making sub-lists form list in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have list of people which contains Name and Id(from one to three) of each person. How can make sub-lists where people will be separated by ids. I am using Java language.
example: 

**Main List:**

> Michael - 2, Joe - 3, Abe - 2, Ivy - 1, George -3...

**Sublists:**

> List 1:  Ivy - 1
>  List 2:  Michael - 2, Abe - 2
>  List 3:  Joe -
>   3, George -3

Comment: What have you already produced?

Comment: You need a multimap (`Map<Integer, List<String>>`) instead of a plain `List`, as Gavin suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring Java 8 and Streams, and the oddity that more than one person shares an id, iterate over the list and for each id add a list to a `Map` of `Id -> List<Name>` if no list exists, or add a name to the list if the id exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a class which has a constructor which takes in two parameters

```
public class PersonID
private int id;
private string person
public PersonID(int id, string person)
{
 this.person = person;
 this.id = id;
}
```

Create getters/setters for each member

After this create the main Arraylist of PersonID, then use a simple for loop to step through the list and select those entries with ID = 2 for example

I hope this answers your question!

Comment: So you would make a method called getSubList(ArrayList<PersonID> list, Int id) which loops through the list and returns a sublist.